# CCRC command for rmstream

Tags: cleartool, clearcase-remote-client

1. Cleartool has a command `cleartool rmstream` to delete a specific stream. But in CCRC there is no corresponding command. From GUI also, there is no option to delete the stream. Anyone has any solution to this? Views can be deleted.
2. Similarly, for `cleartool rmbranch` is there any alternative command in CCRC?

Why complete command support is not provided in CCRC, people are not supposed to use CCRC??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, this does not seem supported (not from a [CTE ClearTeam Explorer even 9.x](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/0_helpindex_ccrc.htm)), so not from IBM Rational ClearCase Web (CCWeb) or IBM Rational ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC)

That means an admin has to delete the stream on the  IBM Rational Web Platform (RWP) server side.

> Why complete command support is not provided in CCRC, people are not supposed to use CCRC??

Because CCRC is meant to be used by clients, and `rmstream`/`rmbranch` are consider "administrative" commands, better done on the server side by admins.

Comment: BTW, if I have multiple streams created but corresponding views are removed via CCRC GUI, is there any issue with keeping all those streams without removing them? Will that eat up any space on my system/server?

Comment: @Ravi No: it will not eat that much space on the server. Only versions created on the associated branches of those stream could be costly in term of storage. But the streams themselves are lightweight.

Comment: Added more to the original question.